# Preg_match to match phone number

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a csv file with about 2000 websites in it, I have a script working that file_get_contents of each site, and looks for a phone number.

My preg match is not working!!??
I need to find the exact number string 800-885-7505

I tried:

```
preg_match('/^800-885-7505$/', $page, $matches);
```

But didnt work.... Can anyone tell me why?
Thank you!

I tried:

```
<?
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  $page = file_get_contents("http://www.".$line[0]);
 preg_match('/800-885-7505/', $page, $matches);
 echo "http://www.".$line[0]." = ".$matches[1] . "<br><br>";
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

This DID work, I have the same script looking for what iframe is on a page, and it works great:

```
<?
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  $page = file_get_contents("http://www.".$line[0]);
  preg_match('/<iframe.*src=\"(.*)\".*><\/iframe>/isU', $page, $matches);
  if (($matches[1]!=="http://www.url.com/lmapp.html") && ($matches[1]!=="http://www.url.com/mc_NewApp2.html"))
  {echo "http://www.".$line[0]." = ".$matches[1] . "<br><br>";}
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

So I thought I all needed to do was get a correct preg-match for the phone number

Comment: unless the whole page only contains **800-885-7505** that's not going to work. look at what the ^ and $ mean

Comment: _Exact number_? Consider `strpos` then.

Comment: how about: if ( preg_match('/800-885-7505/', $page, $matches) ) echo "http://www.".$line[0]." = ".$matches[1] . "<br><br>";

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_match('/800-885-7505/', $page, $matches);
```

or faster:

```
if ( strpos('800-885-7505',$page) !== false )
```

Comment: preg_match('/800-885-7505/', $page, $matches); did not work :(

Comment: it still found all pages in list, even those with out that number

Comment: @user1789437 then you need to provide more code what you are exactly doing and how.

Comment: my code works and preg_match('/800-885-7505/', $page, $matches) returns 1 if $page contains the exact phone number string

Comment: <?
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  $page = file_get_contents("http://www.".$line[0]);
 preg_match('/800-885-7505/', $page, $matches);
 echo "http://www.".$line[0]." = ".$matches[1] . "<br><br>";
}
fclose($file);
?>

Comment: @user1789437 please paste your code in your question so what we can see it easier